# About kivy loop data from python file

Tags: python, loops, kivy

guys
I try to read all data from python file and showing in kivy Label text for looping (date and money), but i'm stuck here :(

If can help will thanks a lot :)

## .py

```
MY_DATA = [
{"date": "22/06/2022", "money": "CNY 1,000.00"},
{"date": "23/07/2022", "money": "CNY 3,000.00"},
{"date": "20/08/2022", "money": "CNY 5,000.00"},]


class MainApp(App, Screen):
    date = MY_DATA[0]["date"]
    money = MY_DATA[0]["money"]

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
```

## .kv

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: app.date
        size_hint: None, None
        width: dp(150)
        height: dp(40)

    Label:
        text: app.money
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: dp(40)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcFHk.png

Comment: Where's your `for` loop ?

Comment: problem solve, thanks :)